# Is there official Docker image of Oracle XE database?

Tags: oracle, docker

I have a simple question - is there any official, ready-to-go Docker image of Oracle XE database? I cannot find anything on Docker Hub, but maybe I'm searching it wrongly.

Comment: For anyone revisiting this question today... It seems like oracle is going to release an official Oracle XE docker image soon!  https://twitter.com/GeraldVenzl/status/1230673245193539585

Comment: https://container-registry.oracle.com/, then look under "database".

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe this is the latest image of oracle-xe database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is no official docker image available but you can refer following git repo to make it

https://github.com/freneticdisc/oracle-blog-examples/tree/master/Docker%20-%20Oracle%20Database

or

https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g

Comment: Oracle also provides Dockerfiles to build an image on your own (also 18c and 19c): https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Answer (score 16):

This seems to be Oracle's official repository for docker - https://github.com/oracle/docker-images
More details here - https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/deliver-oracle-database-18c-express-edition-in-containers

Comment: do you know of any 12.2 express edition?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.